# Don't handle pan gesture on superview when touchdown button (subview)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, view, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view(superview) which I can move by pan gesture, This view has subview(UIButton) with TouchDown Event. But when I press button(touchdown event handled) and continue move finger my superview start handling pan gesture method. 
How disable handling pan gesture method of superview when I touchdown its subview?

Answer (score 0):

for disabling touch events on UIView's subviews you can add this extension to `UIViewController`:

```
extension UIViewController:UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        tap.delegate = self
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    public func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
       if (touch.view!.isDescendantOfView(self.view) && touch.view != self.view){
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```